# Virtualmin cPanel backup migration failed

Tags: backup, webserver, cpanel, webmin, virtualmin

I tried to migrate a cPanel backup into Virtualmin, but it gave me an error saying that I needed a password. Yet, it did not prompt me for a password. This is all it said:

```
Validating migration file ..
.. validation failed : A password must be supplied for cPanel migrations
```

So how can I migrate the cPanel backup into Virtualmin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Virtualmin is able to detect the password for the admin cPanel user, so try insert your own password and check that is helpful.

Comment: I forget how I solved this, but I ended up just getting cPanel in the end; virtualmin just wasn't worth the headache despite being free.

Answer (score 0):

go to virtualmin\add servers\migrate virtual server.

now click ... select your cpanel file and then click ok.
check the radio button for password, and then type a password in the box next to it.

check other values too... it might help to set a username for this domain that will not conflict with users you may create.

afterwards click migrate now all the way at the bottom of page
now patience. if it fails there will be a new reason...